# How to ignore alphanumeric text in Specflow statement from being transformed to parameter?

Tags: c#, specflow

I am creating a SpecFlow scenario (using Visualt Studio) where an alphanumeric text is part of the statement. 
But when I create its definition, the number part of the alphanumeric text changes to parameter. e.g.

```
Scenario: Add two variables
Given the first number is of type S1 and is 50
And the second number is of type S2 and is 70
When the two numbers of type S1 and S2 are added
Then the result should be 120
```

When I right click on the Given statement and create definition, I get the following definition:

```
[Given(@"the first number is of type S(.*) and is (.*)")]
public void Function(int p0, int p1)
```

Instead I wanted was:

```
[Given(@"the first number is of type S1 and is (.*)")]
public void Function(int p0)
```

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow guesses what the regular expression should be when generating a stub for the step definition. Any number appearing in the step is guessed to be a parameter. This is the default behavior, and I do not know of a way to change it. Just modify the step definition pattern so it fits your particular use case.

Comment: Yes, in these cases you have to manually change the regex. The Extension tries to guess as good as it can what are parameters and what not. There is no guarantee that it will always create the regex you want.